# Python for loop error

Tags: python

I'm working on a Python exercise at Codecademy and got stuck on what looks like a simple problem:

> Write a function `fizz_count()` that loops through all the elements of a list. When the element is `'fizz'`, increment a counter called `count`. Then return the value of `count`.

My code:

```
def fizz_count(x):
  count = 0
  for i in x:
    if x[i] == 'fizz':
      count = count + 1
  return count
```

I get this error message:

```
An exception was raised for fizz_count(['fizz', 'buzz']): list indices must 
be integers not str
```

Everything is formatted exactly as shown. I can't figure out where the error is.

Comment: The error tells you *exactly* where the error is - if the list index must be an integer, but is actually a string, then `i` is a string. Why not `print i` to find out why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `x` is a sequence of elements, when you do

```
for i in x:
```

you are looping through the elements of `x`, not through indexes.

So when you do

```
x[i]
```

you are doing

```
x[element]
```

which makes no sense.

**What can you do?**

You can compare the element with `'fizz'`:

```
for element in x:
    if element == 'fizz':
        # ...
```

Comment: Yeah, I just figured it out. This is not C++ :P Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are passing in a list `['fizz', 'buzz'])` so `i` is equal to `fizz` or `buzz` not an integer.
Try `if i =="fizz"`

```
def fizz_count(x):
  count = 0
  for i in x:
    if i  == 'fizz': # i will be each element in your list
      count = count + 1
  return count
```

Answer (score 0):

When you used { for i in x } then here 'i' is the item of the list and not an index. Hence,

Corrected Code is:

```
def fizz_count(x):
  count = 0
  for i in x:
    if i == 'fizz':
      count = count + 1
  return count

print fizz_count(['fizz', 'buzz'])
```

OUTPUT

```
1
```